# navigator.userAgent in Chrome not correct

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, navigator

I use javascript method navigator.userAgent to detect version of browser. But it gives wrong version for Chrome.
My Chrome is **114.0.5735.134**, but the navigator.userAgent show it is **114.0.0.0**.
I would be grateful if some body can give me advice on how to fix this? Thank you.
[image]

[image]

Comment: that's what google have decided to use, it's not incorrect as such -`correct for other browser` are you sure? Firefox 114.0.1 shows 114.0 - why do you feel it's important though? userAgent is spoofable anyway

Comment: Ah Yes, Firefox also wrong. I have just edited my post.

Comment: so, only Edge is "right" ... or in other words, Microsoft have decided to show the whole version, so any bugs in older minor releases can be exploited easily

Comment: So at this moment is there a way to get the exact version info of browser @JaromandaX , or we can only get the major version info. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

At least for Chrome, there's library name: find-chrome-version. This would give you the exact version of Chrome.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/find-chrome-version